# Make a child div sticky at parent level - CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, sticky

I have a div in the inner level, like the child of child of outermost div. I want this div to be sticky in the main level.

```css
.mainParent{
  height: 2000px;
}
.mainWrapper{
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}
.actionsWrapper{
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.stickySection{
  flex: 1;
  height: 70px;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
.textWrapper{
  background-color: blue;
}
.textWrapper p{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='mainParent'>
  <div class='mainWrapper'>
    <div class='textWrapper'>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
    </div>
    <div class='actionsWrapper'>
      <div class='stickySection'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want that black section be sticky outside the actionWrapper also. ie., when the user is at the blue section also, we should be able to see the stickySection div at the bottom. Aso of now, stickySection exhibits sticky behaviour only when the scroll reaches it's immediate parent div actionsWrapper. I want it to be sticky in the level of mainWrapper div or mainParent div. Anybody, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed;` instead of sticky:

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .mainParent {
        height: 2000px;
      }
      .mainWrapper {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: green;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .actionsWrapper {
        height: 500px;
        background-color: yellow;
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
      }
      .stickySection {
        flex: 1;
        height: 70px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: black;
      }
      .textWrapper {
        background-color: blue;
      }
      .textWrapper p {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="mainParent">
      <div class="mainWrapper">
        <div class="textWrapper">
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsom donor</p>
        </div>
        <div class="actionsWrapper">
          <div class="stickySection"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```